# What does the line behind the resource in Google performance tab means?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-console

[image]

The yellow bar is the fetched file but what does the white line behind is supposed to mean? When I hover the line it tells me that the whole thing is the network transfer time but why the yellow bar is so short then? How to understand it?